# Does resurrection heal ability damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The description of the *resurrection* spell states that it restores "life and complete strength to any deceased creature." Does this include any ability damage that the creature may have suffered, prior to its death?

> Upon completion of the spell, the creature is immediately restored to full hit points, vigor, and health

Does this include temporary ability damage and/or permanent ability drain? Or does the creature also require a *restoration* spell to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [d20srd](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/resurrection.htm):

> This spell functions like raise dead, except that you are able to restore life and complete strength to any deceased creature.

...

> Upon completion of the spell, the creature is immediately restored to full hit points, vigor, and health, with no loss of prepared spells. However, the subject loses one level, or 2 points of Constitution if the subject was 1st level. (If this reduction would bring its Con to 0 or lower, it can’t be resurrected). This level loss or Constitution loss cannot be repaired by any means.

[Raise dead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/raiseDead.htm) has a specific ability score healing line in it:

> Any ability scores damaged to 0 are raised to 1.

Thus, Restoration, which "functions as if it's raise dead" but with max-healing does not restore ability damage or drain outside the bounds of raise dead, as "complete strength, health, and vigor" are not ability damage or drain.

Comment: We've played it both ways in the past.  Some interpret health and vigor to include ability drain/damage.

Comment: While that's an interpretation, the power does not explicitly say that, and as it references Raise Dead that does have specific ability healing (though limited) there is little support for that interpretation. You are welcome to post that as an answer, however.